# Pass HTML into a Prop for Nuxt

Tags: vue.js, nuxt.js

I'm trying to pass some HTML inside of a Prop to display an SVG logo.

```
projectSVGLogo: {
  type: String,
  required: false
}
```

Then accessing by

```
<TheCarouselProjects
  projectPath="/tmbc"
  projectImg="image-test"
  projectImgAlt="Alt"
  projectTitle="TMBC"
  projectDescription="Small description"
  projectSVGLogo="<svg id="Layer_1" data-name="Layer 1" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" viewBox="0 0 387.8 58.1"><path d="M782. . ."></path></svg>"
     />
```

My IDE however does not like it.

I tried escaping using the `\` character but no luck.

I did see

```
projectSVGLogo: {
   type: Object,
   default: function () {
     return { svgCode: '<svg stuff here. . .>' }
   }
},
```

But this doesn't really help me because I can't pass my SVG code here as it won't be reusable this way.

Is there another way or something I am missing?

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`v-html`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/api/#v-html) to render your html prop.

But you should consider using [`slot`](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/components-slots.html) instead.